# Client Server IOEception при отключении клиента

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Привет ребят, помогите с ошибкой разобраться:

**Сервер:**

```
TcpClient tcpclient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
     NetworkStream nstream = tcpclient.GetStream();
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nstream, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nstream, Encoding.UTF8);

     while (true)
     {
         string inputline = "";
         while (inputline != null)
         {
             inputline = reader.ReadLine();
             Console.WriteLine("Клиент написал: " + inputline);
         }
```

**Клиент:**

```
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("Подключено");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите сообщение: ");
                string lineToSend = Console.ReadLine();
                writer.WriteLine(lineToSend);
            }
```

Если клиент подключен и закрыть окно, то на сервере возникает ошибка в этой строке:

```
inputline = reader.ReadLine();
```

(Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.)
Пробывал делать так:

```
while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

ничего не получается, как можно клиенту нормально отключаться чтобы сервер и дальше мог принимать клиентов? 2 вопрос: как можно с сервера обратно написать сообщение клиенту? Так как при старте:

```
tcpListener.Start()
```

напрочь блокируется ввод с сервера?

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте разные вопросы в виде отдельных вопросов, а не два-в-одном. Подумайте о других людях, которые будут искать ваш вопрос в поиске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исключение при отвалившемся клиенте - это совершенно нормально. Вам надо просто перехватить это исключение.

Comment: Все спасибо большое, благодаря вашему совету при перехвате исключения, решил проблему как можно оживить сервер. Теперь вопрос как отвечать клиентам.